# How to combine 2 tables with hard constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a hard problem in sql that I can't resolve.

I show you it now:

```
table1 

id    id2    enter_date     exit_date     type
1     5       05/05/2021      11/05/2021    A
1     5       11/05/2021      20/05/2021    B
1     .       20/05/2021      30/05/2021    .
```

```
table2

id    id2    enter_date     exit_date     type
1     5       08/05/2021      14/05/2021    A
1     5       14/05/2021      20/05/2021    B
1     5       20/05/2021      30/05/2021    C
```

My table 1 contains all good values but the problem is that she got missing value ( . )   and in my table2, I have every values. But all the values of table2 which are ever in the table 1 are false. But every value of table2 witch are not ever in table 1 are good.

So with my example, it gives me it :

```
table_final

id    id2    enter_date     exit_date     type

1     5       05/05/2021      11/05/2021    A
1     5       11/05/2021      20/05/2021    B
1     5       20/05/2021      30/05/2021    C
```

SO I have good date, good type and no missing value.

I tried some thing with union all ...  but nothing work.

Thanks for reading me !

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question. Read comments within code

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  table1 (id, id2, enter_date, exit_Date, type) as
  4    (select 1, 5   , date '2021-05-05', date '2021-05-11', 'A'  from dual union all
  5     select 1, 5   , date '2021-05-11', date '2021-05-20', 'B'  from dual union all
  6     select 1, null, date '2021-05-20', date '2021-05-30', null from dual
  7    ),
  8  table2 (id, id2, enter_date, exit_Date, type) as
  9    (select 1, 5   , date '2021-05-08', date '2021-05-14', 'A'  from dual union all
 10     select 1, 5   , date '2021-05-14', date '2021-05-20', 'B'  from dual union all
 11     select 1, 5   , date '2021-05-20', date '2021-05-30', 'C'  from dual
 12    )
 13  -- query that returns result you need
 14  -- Remove "invalid" rows from TABLE1 (the ones whose ID2 and TYPE aren't null
 15  -- (or equal to dot, as you put it)
 16  select *
 17    from table1
 18    where id2 is not null
 19      and type is not null
 20  union
 21  -- From TABLE2, take rows that don't exist in TABLE1 already (matched by ID, ID2 and TYPE)
 22  -- where ID2 and TYPE aren't NULL (in TABLE1).
 23  select *
 24    from table2
 25    where (id, id2, type) not in (select id, id2, type
 26                                  from table1
 27                                  where id2 is not null
 28                                    and type is not null
 29                                 );
```

---

```
        ID        ID2 ENTER_DATE EXIT_DATE  T
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -
         1          5 05/05/2021 11/05/2021 A
         1          5 11/05/2021 20/05/2021 B
         1          5 20/05/2021 30/05/2021 C

SQL>
```